# $N \rtimes H$ vs $H \rtimes N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

When we define the semidirect product for $N \lhd G$ with $H < G$. We assumed $N$ is normal because that makes $f: N \times H \to G$, $f(n,h) = nh$ an isomorphism when we assume $f$ is a bijection. However, I don't know why can't we assume $H$ is normal and define semidirect product differently, namely, $(n_{1},h_{1}) \ast (n_{2},h_{2}) = (n_{1}n_{2},n_{2}h_{1}n_{2}^{-1}h_{2})$, or similarly it generalize to other homomorphism $\mu: N\to Aut(H)$.

> If this is a valid construction, how does it relate to the original construction? Or in other words, if $H$ and $N$ are normal subgroups, I guess there is a natural isomorphism between $H \rtimes N$ vs $N \rtimes H$? By $(a,b) \mapsto (b,a)$?

I have done some search online but did not find much information, and I'm not sure my guess is correct. I'm totally a beginner in algebra and I would appreciate it if you can help me understand this simple question.

Comment: There is certainly no *natural* isomorphism between $H\rtimes N$ and $N\rtimes H$ when in general $N\rtimes H$ is not even isomorophic "to itself" in case we have two different actions of $H$ on $N$ to choose from.

Comment: f is not an isomorphism. That's the whole point of semidirect products. You mean a bijection?

Comment: `@MartinBrandenburg I mean if we assume f is a bijection, then we can define multiplication on $N \times H$ via the typical semidirect product multiplication (via conjugation action) so it can become an isomorphism. I'm not saying the multiplication on direct product, if it's confusing, which I know it might be, would you mind doing a quick edit?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, but is it possible to choose a corresponding action? Like for instance to the conjugation action

Comment: So... suppose we have a morphism $\varphi\colon H\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$, and a morphism $\psi\colon N\to\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ (you have $N\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$ in the post, and I think that's wrong...) We can use $\varphi$ to define a semidirect product structure $N\rtimes_{\varphi} H$ on $N\times H$ by $(x,g)(n,h) = (x\varphi(g)(n),gh)$, and in the resulting group, identifying $N$ with $N\times\{1\}$ and $H$ with $\{1\}\times H$, we have $hnh^{-1}=\varphi(h)(n)$.  We can likewise construct $N{}_{\psi}\!\ltimes H$. And you are asking if there is a connection between these two groups?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes that is what I'm asking. I'm not very familiar with $\ltimes$ though. And I suppose you mean $\phi(n)(g)$ instead of $\phi(g)(n)$?

Comment: There is generally no relation between them other than that they have the same order, and both contain subgroups isomorphic to $N$ and $G$.nThe symbol just tells you which subgroup acts on which subgroup. For example, $S_3=C_3\rtimes C_2$ with the nontrivial action, and $C_6=C_3\ltimes C_2$ with the trivial action. But there is no isomorphism between $S_3$ and $C_6$. What is true is that $N\rtimes_{\phi} H$ is isomorphic to $H{}_{\phi}\ltimes N$. But otherwise you are just asking for isomorphisms between $A\rtimes B$ and $B\rtimes A$. They need not exist.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the answer. Sorry, I think I understand what you mean but would you mind writing out the exact definition of $\ltimes$? And I guess once I understand what you mean, what you said about "what is true that..." would make more sense to me. If you don't mind, just put it in the answer section, and I'll accept it, so this hopefully would help future readers.

Comment: By the way (19 hours too late): no, I meant $\varphi(g)(n)$: note that $\varphi$ takes elements of $H$ as input, and here $g\in H$; so $\varphi(g)$ is a map form $N$ to $N$, and hence $\varphi(g)(n)\in N$ makes sense. Whereas $\varphi(n)(g)$ would *not* make sense, because $\varphi$ is note defined on $N$, it is defined on $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the internal semidirect product, since that informs the construction.

Let $G$ be a group, and assume that:

1. $H\leq G$;
2. $N\triangleleft G$;
3. $NH = G$; and
4. $N\cap H = \{e\}$.

Then every element $x\in G$ can be written uniquely as $x=nh$ with $n\in N$ and $h\in H$. We can write out how multiplication works, since given $x=nh$ and $y=n'h'$, we have
$$xy = (nh)(n'h') = (nh)(n'(h^{-1}h)h') = \Bigl( n (hn'h^{-1})\Bigr)\Bigl(hh'\Bigr).$$
This works since $hn'h^{-1}\in N$, by the normality of $N$.

We can also consider that conjugation by $h$ induces a homomorphism $\varphi\colon H\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$, where $h\in H$ maps to $\varphi_h$, with $\varphi_h(n) = hnh^{-1}$. Then our multiplication rule becomes:
$$xy = (nh)(n'h') = (n\varphi_h(n'))(hh').$$
This suggests the construction of the (external) semidirect product of $N$ by $H$ (via $\varphi$): given any homomorphism $\varphi\colon H\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$, we define a product on the set of all pairs $(n,h)\in N\times H$ by
$$(n,h)\cdot (n',h') = (n\varphi_h(n'), hh'),$$
where $\varphi_h = \varphi(h)\in\mathrm{Aut}(N)$. One then proves that this is indeed a group, that $\mathcal{N}=\{(n,1)\in N\times H\mid n\in N\}$ is a normal subgroup that is isomorphic to $N$; that $\mathcal{H}=\{(1,h)\in N\times H\mid h\in H\}$ is a subgroup isomorphic to $H$; and we have
$$(1,h)(n,1)(1,h)^{-1} = (\varphi_h(n),1),$$
so that conjugation by $h\in\mathcal{H}$ realizes $\varphi_h$. We denote this group by $N\rtimes_{\varphi}H$, with the notation suggesting that (i) the underlying set is $N\times H$; (ii) the subgroup $N$ will be normal; and (iii) $\varphi$ is part of the required information. This group satisfies:

> 1. $\mathcal{H}\leq N\rtimes_{\varphi}H$;
> 2. $\mathcal{N}\triangleleft N\rtimes_{\varphi}H$;
> 3. $\mathcal{N}\mathcal{H} = N\rtimes_{\varphi}H$; and
> 4. $\mathcal{N}\cap\mathcal{H}=\{(1,1)\}$.

Now, the thing is, going back to the original group $G$, since $NH$ is a group, it follows that $NH=HN$. So while every element $x\in G$ can be written uniquely as $x=nh$, it is also true that for every $x\in G$ there exist a unique expression of $x$ as $x=hn$ with $h\in H$ and $n\in N$ (not necessarily the same ones as in the first expression).  Had we started with this expression, we would have the multiplication rule given as follows:  if $x=hn$ and $y=h'n'$, then
$$xy = (hn)(h'n') = hh'((h')^{-1}nh')n'.$$
If we let $\psi_h$ be "conjugation by $h$", then now we have
$$(hn)(h'n') = hh'\psi_{(h')^{-1}}(n)n'.$$
This suggests that we could perform the entire construction using $H\times N$ as our underlying set. Indeed, letting $\psi\colon H\to\mathrm{Aut}(N)$, then we define a group with underlying set $H\times N$, and multiplication given by
$$(h,n)\cdot (h',n') = (hh', \psi_{(h')^{-1}}(n)n').$$
Then one shows that this is indeed a group; that $\mathcal{N}=\{(1,n)\in H\times N\mid n\in N\}$ is a subgroup isomorphic to $N$, that $\mathcal{H}=\{(h,1)\in H\times N\mid h\in H\}$ is a subgroup isomorphic to $H$. And that conjugation of elements of $\mathcal{N}$ by elements of $\mathcal{H}$ is
$$(h,1)^{-1}(1,n)(h,1) = (1,\psi_{h^{-1}}(n)).$$
If we denote this group by $H{}_{\psi}\!\ltimes N$, then we have:

1. $\mathcal{H}\leq H{}_{\psi}\!\ltimes N$;
2. $\mathcal{N}\triangleleft H{}_{\psi}\!\ltimes N$;
3. $\mathcal{H}\mathcal{N}=H{}_{\psi}\!\ltimes N$; and
4. $\mathcal{H}\cap\mathcal{N} = \{(1,1)\}$.

So there was nothing intrinsically important about using $N\times H$ as our underlying set: we could have used $H\times N$. Note in addition that the two constructions are isomorphic if $\psi=\phi$. The key is again going back to the "internal" case: if $x=nh$, then $x = h(h^{-1}nh)$ is how to write it as an element of $H$ times an element of $N$.

So define $\Phi\colon N\rtimes_{\phi}H\to H{}_{\phi}\!\ltimes N$ by $$\Phi(n,h) = (h,\phi_{h^{-1}}(n)).$$
I claim this is an isomorphism. Indeed, to check it is a homomorphism, note that
$$\begin{align*}
\Phi\Bigl( (n,h)(n',h')\Bigr) &= \Phi(n\phi_h(n'),hh')\\
&= \Bigl(hh',\phi_{(hh')^{-1}}(n\phi_h(n'))\Bigr)\\
&= \Bigl(hh',\phi_{(h')^{-1}h^{-1}}(n)\phi_{(h')^{-1}h^{-1}}
(\phi_h(n'))\Bigr)\\
&= \Bigl(hh',\phi_{(h')^{-1}}(\phi_{h^{-1}}(n))\phi_{(h')^{-1}}(\phi_{h^{-1}}
(\phi_h(n')))\Bigr)\\
&= \Bigl(hh',\phi_{(h')^{-1}}(\phi_{h^{-1}}(n))\phi_{(h')^{-1}}(n')\Bigr)\\
&= \Bigl(hh',\phi_{(h')^{-1}}\bigl(\phi_{h^{-1}}(n)n'\bigr)\Bigr).\\
\Phi(n,h)\Phi(n',h') &= \Bigl(h,\phi_{h^{-1}}(n)\Bigr)\Bigl(h',\phi_{(h')^{-1}}(n')\Bigr)\\
&= \Bigl(hh',\phi_{(h')^{-1}}\bigl(\phi_{h^{-1}}(n)\bigr)\phi_{(h')^{-1}}(n')\Bigr)\\
&= \Bigl( hh', \phi_{(h')^{-1}}\bigl( \phi_{h^{-1}}(n)n'\bigr)\Bigr).
\end{align*}$$
So $\Phi$ is a group homomorphism. It is one-to-one, since $\Phi(n,h)=(h,\phi_{h^{-1}}(n))=(1,1)$ if and only if $h=1$ and $1=\phi_{h^{-1}}(n) =\phi_{1}(n) = n$. And it is surjective, since given $(h,n)\in H\times N$, we have
$$\Phi(\phi_h(n),h) = (h,\phi_{h^{-1}}(\phi_h(n))) = (h,\phi_{h^{-1}h}(n)) = (h,n).$$
Thus, $\Phi$ is an isomorphism.

So there is no difference between $N\rtimes_{\phi}H$ and $H{}_{\phi}\ltimes N$, except for how you write things: you get isomorphic groups.  Some people prefer the $N$ coordinate first, some people prefer the $N$ coordinate second. We usually denote it $N\rtimes_{\phi} H$ in *both* cases, however, because we usually use $\triangleleft$ for the normality symbol (and write $N\triangleleft G$); we could just as easily write $G\triangleright N$ all the time, and then it would be more natural to write $H{}_{\phi}\!\ltimes N$, but we don't.

There's also nothing sacred about letting $N$ be the normal subgroup and $H$ be the subgroup acting on $N$; we could just as well say that $H$ is normal and $N$ acts on it and is not necessarily normal... except that we try to use visual cues to help understanding, and $N$ is normally used to denote a **N**ormal subgroup.

So to avoid that cueing, say we have group $H$ and $K$, and morphisms $\phi\colon H\to\mathrm{Aut}(K)$, and $\psi\colon K\to\mathrm{Aut}(H)$. We can then construct $K\rtimes_{\phi}H$ (which we could also construct as $H{}_{\phi}\!\ltimes K$), and we can also construct $K{}_{\psi}\!\ltimes H$ (which we could also construct as $H\rtimes_{\psi}K$). In general, we don't expect the two groups, $K\rtimes_{\phi}H$ and $K{}_{\psi}\!\ltimes H$ to be isomorphic, even though they are both constructed on the underlying set $K\times H$. They *could* be isomorphic, but that will likely just be happenstance.

And more, $K\rtimes_{\phi}H$ is isomorphic to $K{}_{\psi}\!\ltimes H$ via the map that sends $(k,h)$ to $(k,h)$  if and  only if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are both the trivial map and these semidirect product are actually direct products. Indeed, if $\phi$ and $\psi$ are both trivial  then both semidirect products are equal and are direct products. Conversely, if the map is an isomorphism, then the image of $\mathcal{K}=\{(k,1)\mid k\in K\}$ is normal in $K{}_{\psi}\!\ltimes H$, as it $\mathcal{H}=\{(1,h)\mid h\in H\}$ by construction. So we are in the situation where we have two normal subgroup $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ of a group $G$, with $G=\mathcal{NK}$ and $\mathcal{N}\cap\mathcal{K}=\{e\}$. In this situation, it is well known that $nk=kn$ for all $k\in\mathcal{K}$ and $n\in\mathcal{N}$, so we actually have that
$$(k,n) = (k,1)(1,n) = (1,n)(k,1) = (k,\psi_{k^{-1}}(n))$$
for all $k\in K$ and $n\in N$, so $\psi_{k^{-1}}(n)=n$ for all $n$; thus $\psi(k^{-1})=\mathrm{id}_N$, and this holds for all $k$. This yields as well that $\phi$ is the trivial map.